# jquery slider shows all content on load

Tags: jquery, html, load

IE somehow shows the whole div when the page loads (just click a button to see it) befor it resizes to the right size. Is it possible to avoid this since it is really ugly:

http://www.bbp.nl/luuk-test/wac/partners/

In FF it works perfectly fine (not the layout fully, but the slider)

plz help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the script is resizing the div after the DOM element fully loaded. In order to overcome this problem set the width & height to 0 in its CSS property. And then re-size it by script.

```
     Hope this will help
```